# Passing data between pages in Windows 10 (Universal Windows Platform) application. (C# / MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Views:

1. SinglePersonView.xaml (datacontext = SinglePersonViewModel.cs) Note: This is also the Main Page.
2. HouseView.xaml (datacontext = HouseViewModel.cs)

ViewModels:

1. SinglePersonViewModel.cs
2. HouseViewModel.cs

Model:

1. Person.cs

In this hypothetical situation, I have a Person object instantiated in the SinglePersonViewModel.cs file. I perform some operations on that object. I navigate to the HouseView.xaml with a button click. The intention here is to be able to see that Person object in the HouseView.xaml and also have the ability to manipulate its properties. The intent is to be able to access and modify the properties in this Person in all views.

Rules:

1. The Person class cannot be static.
2. The Person object, once created, needs to be accessible from all Views.

Question / Summary:

How do you pass data between pages? Should I be creating the instances of Person in a different location other than the SinglePersonViewModel.cs? If so, where, and how should that be implemented?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MVVM pattern you have not only `View` and `ViewModel` parts. As a data source to your `ViewModel` you should create `Model` class that will control your person persistence.

For example, you are creating or retrieving Person object in `SinglePersonViewModel`. First you should call model to have an instance:

```
Person = personsModel.Get(personId);
```

Then you manipulate person properties and save it:

```
personsModel.Save(Person);
```

Now you are open `HouseViewModel` and wants to have a person instance. Just call model to retrieve it:

```
Person = personsModel.Get(personId);
```

You can also use [mvvmlight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) messenger (or other [EventAggregator*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) implementation) to interchange messages from viewmodels.

[Here is an example](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/).

**Sending from `SinglePersonViewModel`:**

```
// Sends a notification message with a Person as content.
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<Person>(person, "Select"));
```

**Recieving in `HouseView`:**

```
// Registers for incoming Notification messages.
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Person>>(this, (message) =>
{
    // Gets the Person object.
    var person = message.Content;

    // Checks the associated action.
    switch (message.Notification)
    {
        case "Select":
            break;
        case "Delete":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

> For low-coupled communication between modules (not only ViewModels) we
>   can try to implement [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern. Event aggregator
>   helps to implement subscriber/publisher pattern in low-coupled app. I
>   know few different implementations.
>
> First one based on [CodeProject post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/812461/Event-Aggregator-Pattern) and uses WeakReference that
>   will help you to prevent memory leak. I will not publish whole code
>   because you can just download source code and use it. In this
>   implementation you must to implement ISubscriber interface for your
>   subscribers.
>
> The second is [Microsoft Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) implementation. This is an open
>   source project then you can see [interface](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.PubSubEvents/IEventAggregator.cs), [implementation](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.PubSubEvents/EventAggregator.cs)
>   and [base event class](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Prism.PubSubEvents/EventBase.cs). In this implementation you must unsubscribe
>   from the event manually.
>
> The third and the last is MVVMLight library and its [Messenger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx)
>   class.
>
> As you can see all of this implementations uses Singleton pattern for
>   saving subscribers.

Comment: I'm fairly new to MVVM. I really don't understand where you are calling the "Get" and "Save" methods from on the Person class. Edit: On the receiving side, we are just placing it into the code behind the HouseView, and not in the HouseViewModel?

Comment: Nononno use ViewModels methods and properties. 
You can call "Get" methods in the constructor or in the other place when your model initializes. 
Call "Save" method in the explicit scenario, for example in command handler when Save button was clicked or in the implicit scenario each time data changes or on form closed (uninitialized).

Comment: So I ended up using the Frame.Navigate(typeof(HouseView), Person) statement which passes the object to the new Frame. I can retrieve from the HouseView code behind using the "OnNavigatedTo". But that still leaves me unable to use it. Is it not possible to pass this object into the HouseViewModel? Since the HouseViewModel is the DataContext for the for the HouseView. I still need the object in the HouseViewModel for the sake of Binding.

Comment: Ok, another one time.
1. Create PersonsModel that will store Person objects.
2. Add PersonsModel to the HouseViewModel by passing it in constructor or creating it by new keyword.
3. Call Get method and initialize HouseViewModel property by the result of this method.

Comment: I hope this tutorial will also can be helpful. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level